# Stopping CoordinatorLayout animations under certain conditions

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library

### I've got the following xml layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:scaleX="0"
        android:scaleY="0"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.behavior.FABAppear"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now within the toolbar I have an edittext that is shown when I press search on the floatingactionbutton, but as I have a list inside the FrameLayout the toolbar is scrolled ofscreen, which is not the intended action. Is there a way to disable the toolbar from beeing hidden in code?